# recursive postgres SQL optimization

Tags: postgresql, recursion, optimization

We are using [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) in our rails project. There are about ~800 categories in the table:

```
db => SELECT id, ancestry FROM product_categories LIMIT 10;

id  |  ancestry
-----+-------------
399 | 3
298 | 8/292/294
 12 | 3/401/255
573 | 349/572
707 | 7/23/89/147
201 | 166/191
729 | 5/727
 84 | 7/23
128 | 7/41/105
405 | 339

(10 rows)
```

`ancestry` field represents "path" of record. What I need is to build a map { category_id => [... all_subtree_ids ... ]}

I solved this by using subqueries like this:

```
SELECT id, 
  (
    SELECT array_agg(id)
    FROM product_categories
    WHERE (ancestry LIKE CONCAT(p.id, '/%') OR
           ancestry = CONCAT(p.ancestry, '/', p.id, '') OR
           ancestry = (p.id) :: TEXT)
  ) categories
FROM product_categories p
ORDER BY id
```

which results in

```
1 | {17,470,32,29,15,836,845,837}
2 | {37,233,231,205,107,109,57,108,28,58, ...}
```

BUT the problem is this query runs about 100ms and I wonder if there's a way to optimize it using `WITH recursive`? I'm novice in WITH so my queries just hang the postgres :(

** ========= UPD ========= **
accepted AlexM answer as fastest, but if any one interested, here's recursive solution:

```
WITH RECURSIVE a AS
(SELECT id, id as parent_id FROM product_categories
 UNION all
 SELECT pc.id, a.parent_id FROM product_categories pc, a
 WHERE regexp_replace(pc.ancestry, '^(\d{1,}/)*', '')::integer = a.id)

SELECT parent_id, sort(array_agg(id)) as children FROM a WHERE id <> parent_id group by parent_id order by parent_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, I think it should be much faster than nested queries:

```
WITH product_categories_flat AS (
    SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(ancestry, '/')) as parent
    FROM product_categories
)
SELECT parent as id, array_agg(id) as children
FROM product_categories_flat
GROUP BY parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Odds are that a join is faster:

```
SELECT p1.id, 
       p2.array_agg(id)
FROM product_categories p
   JOIN product_categories p2
      ON p2.ancestry LIKE CONCAT(p1.id, '/%')
         OR p2.ancestry = CONCAT(p1.ancestry, '/', p1.id)
         OR p2.ancestry = p1.id::text)
GROUP BY p1.id
ORDER BY p1.id;
```

But to say something definite, you'd have to look at `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.